# Python MySQLdb iterate through table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a MSQL db and I need to iterate through a table and perform an action once a WHERE clause is met. Then once it reaches the end of the table, return to the top and start over.

Currently I have

```
cursor = database.cursor()    
cursor.execute("SELECT user_id FROM round WHERE state == -1 AND state = 2")  
round_id = cursor.fetchone()

if round != 5
   ...do stuff
```

in a loop but this obviously only keeps looping the first entry. I guess you need to use the for in function to read through the table, but I'm not sure exactly how to do this using mysqldb?

Comment: you can get the results of the query by calling `cursor.fetchone()` repeatedly (in a `while` for example) until it returns `(None,)`

Comment: i believe you can simply do a for loop through your `cursor.execute()`

Comment: @PurityLake no you can't. `cursor.execute` returns the number of rows. You can do `for item_idx in range(cursor.execute()): something = cursor.fetchone()`

Comment: sorry, barely scanned over the execute function

Comment: to tell the truth, I didn't know it returned the number of rows :)

Comment: @DJV, It took me a while to find an authoritative answer (not having a MySQL database to play with made testing this code tricky), many examples show `.execute()` returning rowcount, but Python Database API Specification v2.0 clearly says it does not, so I went with `.rowcount`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will set the cursor at the beginning of the result set and tell you how many rows it got back (I went back and forth on this one, but [this is the most authoritative documentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14) I have found, older Python MySQLdb lib returned rowcount on execute, but Python Database API Specification v2.0 does not, this should be the most compatible)

```
cursor.execute("SELECT user_id FROM round WHERE state = -1 OR state = 2")
numrows = cursor.rowcount
```

Will tell you how many Rows you got in return

```
for x in xrange(0,numrows):
  row = cursor.fetchone()
  print row[0], "-->", row[1]
```

Will iterate over each row (no need to enumerate x with range)

Comment: worth noting that the query is erroneous

Comment: and now it's only impossible :)

Comment: AHAHA, this is what I get for trying to fix an obvious bug without reading the whole thing :P

Comment: for large tables do "for x in xrange(0,numrows)"
xrange is generator, while range creates an list object which takes time and memory for large numrows

Comment: Would you have a row[1] given that you're only selecting the user_id?

Answer (score 17):

Once you have results in the cursor, you can iterate right in it.

```
cursor = database.cursor()    
cursor.execute("SELECT user_id FROM round WHERE state == -1 AND state = 2")  
for round in cursor:
  if round[0] != 5
    ...do stuff
```

Comment: can you explain what you just wrote either by tags or manually write it ..cause i am having trouble understanding it @codeforester