# Python MySQLdb delete all rows that meet condition

Tags: python, mysql

I want to delete all rows in a table that match a certain value (`userId`)

I've been looking at this post ([Python MySQLdb iterate through table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397239/python-mysqldb-iterate-through-table#)) trying to get it to work how I want it.

I have a `users` table and an `images` table.

`users`:
[image]

`images`:

[image]

In my python script, I've only pulled in the userName. So first

- I need to get the `userId` of the user using the passed-in `userName`. (I have the following `SELECT` statement, but don't know how to assign the result to a variable)

  ```
  import MySQLdb

  dbb = MySQLdb.connect(host="ipaddress",     
  user="root",    
  passwd="myPassword",
  db="myDatabase")

  user_name = "user"

  cursor = dbb.cursor()    
          cursor.execute("""SELECT userId FROM users WHERE userName ='%s'""" (user_name))

  var users_id = 0 // need to assign users_id to the selected userId from above code
  ```

Then

- I need to iterate through the `images` table and delete all rows with the corresponding `userId`

  ```
  cursor2 = dbb.cursor()    
  cursor2.execute("""SELECT FROM images WHERE userId='%s'""" (users_id))  
  for cursor2: //don't think this is right...
  //DELETE all rows with matching users_id
  ```

Comment: What python script?  You haven't posted any code.

Comment: @ScottHunter Added what I could

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the rows produced by a `SELECT` statement as if the `execute` method returned a list of rows.